# Is there an easier/better way to use a pre-defined dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dictionary of numbers corresponding to dates. I have to imagine there's a better method than the one I have to store all the dates, then recall them.

To put it another way, can I make a dictionary in common that's then accessible to other pieces in the code, so I'm not hiding a global dictionary in a function?

```
 Function Get_Val_Date(Val_Date_Key As Long)
        Dim Date_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set Date_Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Date_Dict.Add 1, "9/30/1997"
    Date_Dict.Add 2, "9/30/1998"
    Date_Dict.Add 3, "9/30/1999"
    Date_Dict.Add 4, "9/30/2000"
    Date_Dict.Add 10, "9/30/2001"
    Date_Dict.Add 11, "9/30/2002"
    Date_Dict.Add 12, "9/30/2003"
    Date_Dict.Add 13, "9/30/2004"
    Date_Dict.Add 14, "9/30/2005"



    Get_Val_Date = Date_Dict(Val_Date_Key)

 End Function
```

Comment: FWIW I don't think "late binding" means what you think it does. Anything declared `As Object` or `As Variant` will only be resolved at run-time - that's all "late binding" means.

Comment: Hm. I was under the impression that "Late-binding" meant that the library was declared as part of the object, which meant that even if the reference was turned off, it would be able to find and pull the proper reference. "Early-binding" would never show up in code, hence mentioning it.

Comment: You can always get the type library from the object, regardless of how it's bound.  That's just a fundamental part of how COM works. Early binding just means that the information from the type library can be used during the compile process instead of having to evaluate it at run-time (which is typically slower - early binding lets you pay that overhead up front.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cache it the first time you use it:

```
 'Module level
 Private Date_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary

 Function Get_Val_Date(Val_Date_Key As Long)
    If Date_Dict Is Nothing Then
        Set Date_Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Date_Dict.Add 1, "9/30/1997"
        Date_Dict.Add 2, "9/30/1998"
        Date_Dict.Add 3, "9/30/1999"
        Date_Dict.Add 4, "9/30/2000"
        Date_Dict.Add 10, "9/30/2001"
        Date_Dict.Add 11, "9/30/2002"
        Date_Dict.Add 12, "9/30/2003"
        Date_Dict.Add 13, "9/30/2004"
        Date_Dict.Add 14, "9/30/2005"
    End If

    Get_Val_Date = Date_Dict(Val_Date_Key)

 End Function
```

If you intend to use the same dictionary in other functions, you can split the initializer out into its own `Sub`, something like this:

```
Function Get_Val_Date(Val_Date_Key As Long)
   InitializeDateLookup
   Get_Val_Date = Date_Dict(Val_Date_Key)
End Function

Sub InitializeDateLookup()
    If Date_Dict Is Nothing Then
        Set Date_Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Date_Dict.Add 1, "9/30/1997"
        Date_Dict.Add 2, "9/30/1998"
        Date_Dict.Add 3, "9/30/1999"
        Date_Dict.Add 4, "9/30/2000"
        Date_Dict.Add 10, "9/30/2001"
        Date_Dict.Add 11, "9/30/2002"
        Date_Dict.Add 12, "9/30/2003"
        Date_Dict.Add 13, "9/30/2004"
        Date_Dict.Add 14, "9/30/2005"
    End If
End Sub
```

Then any procedure that needs it can just call the one-liner `InitializeDateLookup`.

Comment: Alternatively, if the dictionary doesn't need to be used anywhere else, you can declare it as a `Static` local. Or, cache it in a `Property Get` procedure.

Comment: The third alternative would be to wrap it in a pre-declared class module.  There's a bunch of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I'm actually trying to move away from class module - the old version was in a class module and causing everyone headaches